# auto_explain on session not working for postgresql 11

Tags: postgresql

I have used this code to get the query plan of my function. It didn't create any logs . It ran successfully and result is coming. Can any one help me to get the query plan of query inside the function. I used this script to get the query plan.

```
LOAD 'auto_explain';
SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0;
SET auto_explain.log_analyze = true;
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on;
select get_report('{"fromDate":"2019-01-22","toDate":"2019-11-29","storeId":1}');
```

Comment: Did you remember to set `shared_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'` in your `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: I need this only for my session. Is that required to set that on postgresql.conf file?

Comment: @richyen It is not necessary to load `auto_explain` at server start.

Comment: After making changes on conf file also not logging query plan. Can any one tell me the needed configurations have to do to get function query plan.

Comment: It works for me.  Are you looking in the right spot for the logs?

Answer (score 1):

To get the plans of nested statements logged,

```
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on;
```